# Spring 4 and OSGI

Tags: spring, osgi, eclipse-gemini

I want to use Spring in an application which loads several modules using OSGi. I want to be able to inject beans exposed by bundle A into targets exposed by bundle B.

I saw blueprint which seems to require Spring 3, and eclipse gemini which supports Spring 4 but seems pretty abandoned.

What's the latests on using OSGi with Spring 4?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BLueprint is independent from spring. For example Aries Blueprint does not need any spring dependency. I am not sure about Gemini but I think it also does not require spring. Blueprint is optimized for OSGi and works well. It does not provide all spring features though.

Spring never worked well in OSGi. Spring 4 now even is not delivered as bundles. So I would not suggest to use spring in OSGi at all.

That said Apache Karaf offers spring 4 bundles but I am not sure how well they work. In any case I doubt you will get any OSGi support from spring source.